# Compare 2 *.txt files and print difference between them

Tags: java, file, printing, compare, difference

I have a problem wrtting the code for comparing two files (first reference file):

```
       PROTOCOL STATE SERVICE
       1        open  icmp
       6        open  tcp
       17       open  udp
```

and (execution file)

```
      PROTOCOL STATE  SERVICE
      1        open   icmp
      6        open   tcp
      17       open   udp
      255      closed unknown
```

and save difference between these two files in new file (255      closed unknown).

For comparing I have used following code but it seems it doesn't work.

```
public String[] compareResultsAndDecide(String refFile, String execFile) throws IOException {

    String[] referenceFile = parseFileToStringArray(refFile);
    String[] execCommand = parseFileToStringArray(execFile);
    List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();


    for(int i = 1; i < execCommand.length ; i++)
    {
        boolean foundString = false; // To be able to track if the string was found in both arrays
        for(int j = 1; j < referenceFile.length; j++)
        {
            if(referenceFile[j].equals(execCommand[i]))
            {
                foundString = true; 
                break; // If it exist in both arrays there is no need to look further
            }
        }
        if(!foundString) // If the same is not found in both..
            tempList.add(execCommand[i]); // .. add to temporary list
    }



    String diff[] = tempList.toArray(new String[0]);


    if(diff != null)  {

                    return diff;
    }
```

For String `refFile` I would use `/home/xxx/Ref.txt` path to reference file. And the same for `execFile` (second file shown up).
Anyone can help me with this?

Just to add, I'm using for parsing File to String Array:

```
public String[] parseFileToStringArray(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(filename));
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                    lines.add(sc.nextLine());
    }
    String[] arr = lines.toArray(new String[0]);
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Doesn't work"?

Comment: For staters, array element count starts from `0` in Java. Not `1`.

Comment: "Doesn't work" means that it returns execFile not the difference between execFile and reference file.

Comment: May be some error in `parseFileToStringArray()` method?

Comment: For that I'm using:

Comment: It's better to add this method to your question, as an edit !

Comment: Yes, sorry, I have added as edit to my question!

Comment: Why is this tagged  "printing"?

Answer (score 1):

Change `int i = 1` to `int i = 0` and `int j = 1` to `int j = 0`

Answer (score 0):

your compareResultsAndDecide method has to be changed like :

```
public static String[] compareResultsAndDecide(String refFile, String execFile) throws IOException {

    String[] referenceFile = parseFileToStringArray(refFile);
    String[] execCommand = parseFileToStringArray(execFile);
    List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();

    List<String> diff = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(execCommand));
    diff.removeAll(Arrays.asList(referenceFile));
    String[] toReturn = new String[diff.size()];
    toReturn = diff.toArray(toReturn);
    return toReturn;
}
```

and your parseFileToStringArray like:

```
    public String[] parseFileToStringArray(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            lines.add(sc.nextLine());
        }
        String[] arr = new String[lines.size()];
        return lines.toArray(arr);
    }
```

Comment: I will try with changing int i = 1 to int i = 0 and int j = 1 to int j = 0.

Comment: The thing is that reference file is something that is static. It is file with which everey executed file will be compared. Executed file is the file as result of one command (nmap) and, probably, it will be changed with each run. So, I will run nmap (for which I have wrote code) and result will be saved as executed file. That file should be compared with that reference file and printout difference between those two files.

Comment: It does not matter wether one of your file is static or not as long as you manage to read them and load the content in your arrays as shown in your code. I will edit my answer so that you are able to try it out on your existing code.

Comment: Still getting only executed file!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your `.txt` files. Your encoding must be different.

I know this isn't the best way, but if you use `replaceAll()` method to replace white spaces from your lines of text files, your code should work. But *Unfortunately, you will miss the spaces between lines*.

Change:

```
String[] arr = lines.toArray(new String[0]);
```

To:

```
String[] arr = lines.toArray(new String[0]).replaceAll(" ", "");
```

**Note:**

1. I tried using `trim()` but it didn't worked well for me.
2. As I mentioned above, array elements starts from `0`, not from `1`. Change that too.

Comment: Yes, I think that white spaces cause problems.

Comment: I don't have possibility to use this replaceAll.